# symfony2 and twig: get properties of form field

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am trying to create a form with sub-fields with symfony2.

In twig I render the form as

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}

      {{ form_errors(form) }}
      <div>
      {{ form_label(form) }}
      {{ form_errors(form) }}

      {% for field in form %}
            {{ form_widget(field) }}
      {% endfor %}

      </div>

    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

However, I want to add some customization depending on the field I am rendering.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}

      {{ form_errors(form) }}
      <div>
      {{ form_label(form) }}
      {{ form_errors(form) }}

      {% for field in form %}
          {% if field.label == "myvalue" %}  <-- this code is not working
            {# do something here #}
            {{ form_widget(field) }}
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      </div>

    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

I am not able to access the label of each of my sub-fields in twig. 
I think it is possible with something like
{{ field.vars.something }}
, but I did not manage to find any clear documentation about this.

Can someone please help? 
Thank you!

**Edit:**

I actually found the answer to my question:
It was indeed just
              {{ field.vars.label }}

and

```
          {% if field.vars.label == "myvalue" %}
            {# do something here #}
            {{ form_widget(field) }}
          {% endif %}
```

did the trick.
However, I am still looking for some good documentation about this "vars" attribute in twig, and what can be retrieved with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll find more information at http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#more-about-form-variables

On that page you'll find a list of common form vars. You might also create custom vars by implementing the buildView method of a FormType. You can read an example at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html#adding-the-extension-business-logic

Hope it'll help